# Orienteering skill organized trainings in Germany?

Tags: navigation, maps, germany, orienteering

Are there any schoolings/trainings for orienteering skills in Germany?

I hike during weekends, but mostly using GPS (geocaching) or using trails, so there's not much opportunity to fully train orienteering skills. **Orienteering runs are not for me**, because I'm hiker, not runner. Rogaining is too extreme.

In Poland, I was using opportunities such as trainings organized by student's outdoor organizations, or on orienteering marches, where individuals had to navigate to the selected points using the maps such as that:

[image]

I think that what I'm looking for is at most similar to **pathfinding** or some **military marches** done in woodlands.

Are there any similar options to train orienteering skills in Germany? For example, student organizations or orienteering/outdoor schools? I was trying to find something like that, but without success.

Comment: We used to do that as kids with the scouts. I'm not aware of any student organizations, though. But I'm aware of a whole bunch of people (including me) who prefer to hike off the crowded trails, and often also as the crow flies. You can send me an email: https://r-forge.r-project.org/users/cbeleites/

Answer (score 2):

There's a German organization. Their website can be found [here](http://www.orientierungslauf.de/).

It's best for you to ask them for further information. You can contact one of [these people](http://fv.orientierungslauf.de/kontakt.html).

Comment: But as the name suggests, they are runners... and I've excluded running in my question. I mean something more like that what pathfinders are doing.

Comment: i think your best practice is to ask them, sure they need something to make a competition that's the speed part, but i'm sure they are able to help you out, just ask them nicely